# Layer.SetOrigin Applies to Java, not HTML5 (PlayN)

Tags: html, gwt, playn

The `Layer` class has a convenient `SetOrigin(x, y)` function to allow positioning/scaling around the origin. I always set this to the center of the image so that I can rotate about the center.

This seems to work only in the Java version and not the HTML5 version. Here's a screenshot of the Java version, where the two items are correctly overlayed (rotate about center)

[image]

Here's what the generated HTML5 version looks like:

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: I use setOrigin and it works in both Java and HTML5. Can you post code?

Comment: Also, what browser are you using? HTML5 has two backends, WebGL and one that uses divs and CSS. The latter will be going away soon in favor of a rewrite based on Canvas. If the bug is in the divs+CSS backend, and not in the WebGL backend, it will probably also be fixed in the new Cavnas-based backend.

Comment: @samskivert I will try to post the code later tonight. I'm using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that you're calling SetOrigin based on the dimensions of an Image that hasn't yet loaded?

I tend to use `SetOrigin` only within my `ResourceCallback`s like so:

```
paddleImage = assetManager().getImage("images/paddle.png");
paddleImage.addCallback(new ResourceCallback<Image>() {
  @Override
  public void done(Image resource) {
    centerX = resource.width() / 2;
    centerY = resource.height() / 2;
    paddleLayer.setOrigin(centerX, centerY);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why would this run ok in Java but not HTML5?

Comment: This code does run correctly in Java and HTML5. If you _don't_ wait for the image to load, it will appear to run correctly on Java, where the assetManager can get the data synchronously, and then surprise you when you try to run on the web, where the load is asynchronous (hence the callback).